# Xcode building "old" code after a pull

Tags: ios, xcode, git, interface-builder, xib

I have a single view App. very basic not much going on right now besides networking code.

Earlier in the day I committed changes to the main view (added buttons, text fields, styling). I did this by copy+paste -ing from an old project. Everything worked as I expected.

Now, I am on a different machine and pulled the changes in. The App is building with the "old" view (just a single button). Why is it not showing the changes that I made, and were working, earlier?

EDIT: its not just the view that isnt updating. Its running all of the old code from my previous commit. Again, the problem is that I have all up to date files.

this is a Swift app, if it matters.

Comment: The simulator sometimes caches xib and storyboard files. Does the problem get resolved if you reset the simulator?

Comment: this is on my device, but i will try that.

Comment: restarting my device did not solve the problem.

Comment: Does the xib appear correctly within Xcode? What about in the simulator? Did you try reinstalling the app on your device?

Comment: does appear correctly within Xcode, tried reinstalling the app.

however, when i try to run on simulator, i get "Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments". This is a new clue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the build folder in my project directory fixed my problem.

Comment: Doing a clean would probably have also solved the problem. You should accept your own answer if you've found a solution.

Comment: in this case the clean didnt solve the problem. had to go in there and manually delete. i will accept after the 2 day waiting period.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your changes didn't get committed/pushed for some reason. Maybe the XIB/storyboard isn't under source control.

Comment: All the files are there. Both on my machine and in the remote repository.